# how to make a screw thread

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode, transforms

I'm currently working on some 3D-Objects that can be mounted on a PCB Chip. So there is one component that has some sort of screw thread on it. How can I achieve it? Is there more than one way to do it?

Thanks again
God Bless

Comment: check the Screw modifier?

Comment: There is a built-in addon to generate screws called Bolt Factory. You just have to enable it in the Preferences.

Comment: Hi and welcome. A screw can be done from *"screw modifier"*, for instance, but how the screw thread you are talking about ends with (as this is eventually the difficult part)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys